# I can't access SQL Server remotely

Tags: sql-server, remote-access, remote-server

I have two instances of SQL Server installed on my server. When I try to connect to the server remotely, I can ONLY connect to the second instance (which is surrounded in RED) in red as shown in the attached snapshot.

My data is on the first instance (which is surrounded in GREEN) I can't find the that instance in the SQL Server Configuration Manager as shown also in the attached snapshot. Any solutions please?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci) Please clarify you have followed *all* the instructions there.

Comment: I also suggest you think about normalizing your relationship with Microsoft (ie get activated)

Comment: 8.0.194? SQL Server 2000? RTM, no less??? Microsoft hasn't even supported SQL Server 2008 R2 for a couple of years now, it's really long past time to upgrade.

Comment: From memory SQL Server Configuration Manager was introduced with SQL Server 2005. Before that you're probably looking for its predecessor, SQL Server Service Manager, but that only allowed you to stop/start/pause services, so you'll probably need to dive into Registry settings.